# Problems when it comes to committing changes to git after running 'npm run deploy' on my react app

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

So I have successfully deployed my react project on GitHub pages, there are a lot of useful guides on how to do this. However I am having issues when it comes to updating the project (it is harder to find good guides on this)

So lets say I make a change to my project on the code as it exists in folders on my computer.

Then I will run 'npm run deploy'. After doing this, I can see my changes have been successfully implemented on my online deployed site, so all good.

Then I run the following code to push the changes into the repository:

```
git add .

git commit -m "update"
```

That works fine, but I get an error at the next step:

```
git push -u origin master
```

When I do this I always get the same error message in the terminal:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/redacted/redacted.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can anyone please explain what is happening here, and what this error message means.

In the error message, does 'remote' mean the code as it exists in the GitHub repo, and 'local' mean the code on my computer? Why does the remote code and local code diverge after running 'npm run deploy'? In future, what is the best way for me to update the repository so that I don't keep running into this problem.

If it's important, here are my scripts on the package.json file:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
```

Comment: Are you trying to have both your source code *and* the GitHub Pages deployment on the master branch? Those aren't going to be compatible histories. You can only do that with GHP if your build is in a directory named `docs/` and you commit the build outputs *with* the changes to the source (which you don't need the `gh-pages` module for).

Comment: "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally" - Are you making changes on github? You don't have the latest changes i.e. if you updated the Readme etc. You'll need to run git pull beforehand to get the latest information. Then you can push

Comment: @jonrsharpe maybe that's my problem, maybe I am unintentionally trying to have the source code and the GitHub Pages deployment on the same master branch, I'm not sure. Why is that happening? How do I change that?

Comment: Well you explicitly asked gh-pages to deploy to the master branch - if that's *not* what you want, pick a different one (or let it use the default, also named gh-pages).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was just following instruction from Create-React-App documentation on deploying a react app to a user page on GitHub pages - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ . It says: "If you are deploying to a GitHub user page instead of a project page you'll need to make one additional modification: Tweak your package.json scripts to push deployments to master:  add "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build" to scripts.' So why are they advising that? You would advise I change this line to "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"?

Comment: There are (or used to be) different limitations around different kinds of site - *are* you trying to deploy the user/org site rather than the project site? And you *can* deploy the site to master, but then you can't also push the source to it - you can't have two commits being the head of one branch, that makes no sense. https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks Jon, these comments put me on the right track. I started all over again, changed the deploy line to "gh-pages -d build". So, as you explained, now when I run 'npm run deploy" my project is published and a build code is pushed in a 'gh-pages' branch on my repo. Then in the terminal i can run 'git add .', 'git commit -m "message" ', and 'git push -u origin master', and my original code is pushed, error-free, into the master branch of the repo. I didn't really understand about branches before, or what all these commands were doing, but I feel I have a grasp on it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
> not [...] have locally.

There are commits on the remote that you don't have locally.  To see them, you can use `git diff`.  First, update the local representation of remote references in your repo:

```
git fetch
```

Now that you have an up-to-date local representation of what's on `origin/master`, you can see the differences with:

```
git diff origin/master
```

Git diff is one of the most important parts of the git tooling, so become acquainted with its syntax.  This should show you what changes you've missed.  you can also pull up the log of `origin/master` which will show the commit messages, authors, and dates with:

```
git log origin/master
```

If this loads up in an editor you don't recognize and the lower left of the screen is a `:` colon character, type `q` to quit.  This program is called `less`.

All that helps you introspect the remote changes that you haven't incorporated locally.  When you're ready to pull them into your own branch, simply issue:

```
git pull
```

This will apply missing commits to your local branch.  If the local commits change the same lines as the remote commits, you'll end up with a git conflict.  In this case you'll have to look at the conflicts and decide how to combine the two changes.  Often, remote changes can be incorporated without causing any conflicts, but of course it depends on what's been changed on both sides.

A final note.  What you absolutely do *not* want to do is `git push -f`.  This will *force push* your changes to master, *replacing* its current history - in other words, you'll destroy the remote changes.  Never do this.  There's a time and a place for it, and once you get more comfortable with `git diff` and its behavior as a *distributed* change control system, you can revisit that advice.